# Returning a string for the number with prefix 0s

Tags: python, function, loops

I don't understand this question and confused. can anyone show me? It's an exercise in a python book. Only can use loop and function. And based on the question, have to ask the user to enter the number and width.

```
def format(number, width):
```

> The function returns a string for the number with prefix 0s. The size
>   of the string is the width. For example, format(34, 4) returns "0034"
>   and format(34, 5) returns "00034". If the number is longer than the
>   width, the function returns the string representation for the number.
>   For example, format(34, 1) returns "34".

Comment: What don’t you understand?

Comment: what part are you confused about? Note the width of a number is the number of integers it has. So the width of "1234" is 4. The width of "890" is 3. The width of "3" is 1. And so on. That function basically pads the front of the number if the width passed in is bigger than the width of the number. For example, format(34,4) returns "0034" because the width passed in is 4, the width of "34" is 2, 4-2 = 2, so we add 2 zeros in front of 34 and return.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def format(number, width):
    numstr = str(number)
    result = ''
    numstrlen = len(numstr)
    for i in range(width - numstrlen):
        result += '0'
    result += numstr
    return result
```

I would have simply done subtraction, but you said it needed to be a loop.

If you can't use len:

```
def format(number, width):
    numstr = str(number)
    result = ''
    numstrlen = 0
    for c in numstr:
        numstrlen += 1
    for i in range(width - numstrlen):
        result += '0'
    result += numstr
    return result
```

Comment: @albusx: Oops. Fixed the error. So...can you un-downvote me now?

Comment: @albusx: I thought this answer had one upvote...oh well! Sorry! And thank you for not downvoting!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "Only can use loop and function". Since your can use function, you can use almost anything in Python.

The simplest solution:

```
def format(n,w):
    s = str(n)
    return ('0' * w + s)[-max(w,len(s)):]

>>> format(34,4)
'0034'
```

Or you can use a loop:

```
def format(n,w):
    s = str(n)
    result = ''
    for i in range(w - len(s)):
        result += '0'
    return result + s

>>> format(34,1)
'34'
>>> format(34,4)
'0034'
```

Comment: can the function still run without using len? tq for the help :D

Comment: Can not use `len`? Then you can use a loop to calculate the length yourself: `for i in s: length += 1`